# Doesn't prints the entire array properly

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Here is my code for an atm machine. It first asks the user for card number then Pin and then expiry date.

```
char card_number[16];
memset(card_number,0,16);
char pin[4];
memset(pin,0,4);
char exp_date[5];
memset(exp_date,0,5);

printf("Enter Card number \n");
//scanf ("%s",&card_number);
fgets (card_number, 16, stdin);
printf("Enter pin\n");
//scanf ("%s",&pin);
fgets (pin, 4, stdin);
printf("Enter expiry date\n");
//scanf ("%s",&exp_date);
fgets (exp_date, 5, stdin);

char data[25];
memset(data,0,25);
char reply[25];
memset(reply,0,25);
int i = 0;
for(i=0;i<25;i++)
{
    if(i<16)
    {
        data[i] = card_number[i];
    }
    if(i>=16 && i<20)
    {
        data[i] = pin[i-16];
    }
    if(i>=20 && i<25)
    {
        data[i] = exp_date[i-20];
    }
}
printf("data: %s",data);
```

It doesn't takes the input for pin. It just prints out the first 15 char stored in data array. Nothing else. What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after this code snippet

```
if(i<16)
{
    data[i] = card_number[i];
}
```

the array `data` contains also the terminating zero character `'\0'` that was copied from `card_number` and the function `printf`

```
printf("data: %s",data);
```

outputs all characters until this terminating zero is encountered ignoring all other character after it,

Another problem can be that if you entered exactly 16 characters for the array 
`card_number` then the new line character will be still in the input buffer. In this case the second call of the `fgets` will read only this new line character. In this case you should enlarge the arrays by one character.

You should write instead

```
#include <string.h>

//...

card_number[ strcspn( card_number, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
pin[ strcspn( pin, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
exp_date[ strcspn( exp_date, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

strcpy( data, card_number );
strcat( data, pin );
strcat( data, exp_date );
```

Or if you do not want to remove the new line character from the strings then exclude these statements

```
card_number[ strcspn( card_number, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
pin[ strcspn( pin, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
exp_date[ strcspn( exp_date, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

and use only

```
strcpy( data, card_number );
strcat( data, pin );
strcat( data, exp_date );
```

Also there is no need to call `memset`. This can be done by the compiler itself. Just declare the arrays like

```
char card_number[16] = { '\0' };
```

or

```
char card_number[17] = { '\0' };
                ^^^^
```

And it is a bad idea to use magic numbers. It is better to write for example like

```
fgets( card_number, sizeof( card_number ), stdin);
```

Comment: card_number[ strcspn( card_number, "\n" ) ] = '\0' if I use this, aren't I declaring an array with the same name twice?

Comment: @UmairJavaid There is no array declaration. The function strcspn in fact finds the position in the array where the new line character is and it is used as index of the element of the array that will be substituted for the value '\0'.

Comment: oh ok. My bad. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays that read user input are not large enough to hold the data you're putting in.  You need one extra byte for each one to hold the terminating null byte.

```
char card_number[17];
memset(card_number,0,sizeof(card_number));
char pin[5];
memset(pin,0,sizeof(pin));
char exp_date[6];
memset(exp_date,0,sizeof(exp_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

The last character of `card_number` will always be a `char` with value zero (`'\0'`) - that's what `fgets()` does.  Your loop will copy that value over.   The `%s` format will stop when it encounters it.

Your code needs to account for the presence of the `'\0'` (in all the strings) when copying, and ensure the last one is copied (to avoid undefined behaviour with `%s`).

If you are expecting exactly `16` characters to be input before the user hits ENTER, and the array is `16` in length, then either  `fgets()` needs to be called twice (to get the total input in two separate pieces) or the buffer needs to be `17` characters or more.    `fgets()` does not remove the newline (if present) so your code needs to deal with it.    Read the documentation for `fgets()`.

Comment: It also doesn't asks the input for pin. It jumps directly to ask input for expiry date. And I changed the card_number to 17, pin to 17 and exp_date to 6. It still isnt working correctly.

Comment: Then you are still not dealing properly with the presence of zero or newline characters (as per the first two paras of my reply).